# What will be the sql query?

Tags: sql, database, db2

```
Price   Age     Name
3000    30  Ram
2000    20  Ram
1000    10  Ram
5000    40  Sham
6000    50  Sita
```

Write a Sql query and display output as

```
Price   Age     Name
1000    30  Ram
5000    40  Sham
6000    50  Sita
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The query depends one the rules you want applied, e.g.: "show all rows, but for name = 'RAM' show half of the avarage price and the sum of all prices below 20". We cannot know what rules you have in mind. Besides you are supposed to come here with a concrete problem. "Write the query for me" is not a concreate problem. "I have written this query: [...], but all my prices are exactly thrice as high as desired; where is my mistake?" would be for instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MIN(price),
       MAX(age),
       name
  FROM table
 GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

```
select 1000 as price, 30 as age, 'Ram' as name from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select 5000 as price, 40 as age, 'Sham' as name from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select 6000 as price, 50 as age, 'Sita' as name from sysibm.sysdummy1
order by 1;
```

(If you want a query that reads data from the table instead, but leads to the same result, you would have to define the rules you want applied.)

Comment: i think its not his ask but good job lol :)